# How to convert JSON multiple value output into proper JSON format?

Tags: arrays, json, shell, sh

I am trying to convert below output into a valid json output. Cant able to solve this using shell scripts.
Current Output:

```
{ “adapter Type” : “Pass” , “Result” : “ 
    ABCD/AAZZ
    ABCD/AHAG” }, 
 { “Adapter Slot” : “Pass” , “Result” : “
    PCI Slot 3
    PCI Slot 2” }, 
 { “WWN” : “Pass” , “Result” : “ 
    10:01:02:90
    10:02:03:90” }
```

expected output (json):

```
{
    "CUT Sheet ": [{
        "Host Adapter Type": "ABCD/AAZZ",
        "Adapter Physical Location/Slot": "PCI Slot 3",
        "HBA WWN": "10:01:02:90"
    }, {
        "Host Adapter Type": "ABCD/AHAG",
        "Adapter Physical Location/Slot": "PCI Slot 2",
        "HBA WWN": "10:02:03:90"
    }]
}
```

Is it possible to convert? can someone provide solution.

Comment: You can't do like this. This is so wrong. Invalid

Comment: JSON can have all characters but control (e.g. FF, NL, CR, Tab, double quote, backspace and backslash) as keys - and even those have escape versions as provisioned by RFC 7159, @OMiShah. The desired output is indeed valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss the brackets in the current output and line feed between results (maybe a cut and paste problem),but with the output:

```
[   {
    "adapterType": "Pass",
    "Result": "ABCD/AAZZ\nABCD/AHAG"   },   {
    "AdapterSlot": "Pass",
    "Result": "PCI Slot 3\nPCI Slot 2"   },   {
    "WWN": "Pass",
    "Result": "10:01:02:90\n10:02:03:90"   } ]
```

redirect to:

| jq 'map_values(.Result | split("\n")) | transpose | map( {"Host Adapter Type":.[0], "Adapter Physical Location/Slot":.[1], "HBA WWN":.[2]})' | jq -n '."CUT Sheet " |= [inputs]'

generates the output:

```
{
  "CUT Sheet ": [
    [
      {
        "Host Adapter Type": "ABCD/AAZZ",
        "Adapter Physical Location/Slot": "PCI Slot 3",
        "HBA WWN": "10:01:02:90"
      },
      {
        "Host Adapter Type": "ABCD/AHAG",
        "Adapter Physical Location/Slot": "PCI Slot 2",
        "HBA WWN": "10:02:03:90"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

you need the jq installed

Comment: Without jq is it possible to handle this? Problem is cant able to install jq in production environment due to security reason

Comment: Yes, you can use Awk, but the code will be huge. The Linux Standard Base requires Awk, and you may have it in your production environment. Another solution is to use nodejs (javascript), but that is if you have it in the production environment.